# Google locking on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, browser, google

Problem I'm facing is that Google doesn't respond well timed to connection requests send from any browsers known to Linux.

As far as I can tell, this was existent in Mint, which is Ubuntu based.

I have no debug or guess about cause but I'm sure there are people with the same problem.

ping of terminal is untouched but any other browser keeps unloaded, for example; google loads fine, I search for something. Then I decide to search for something else and ta daa: You gotta wait for 30 seconds for Google server to respond.

I tried using google's public DNS without success.

Flare the suggestions & ideas!?

---

OK, I think I "fixed" it.

going to:

```
   about:config
```

and deleting everything contains "google" fixed the load issue!

But of course it screwed almost whole of google. The theme turned back to 90's and the fun started, images or any other search results cannot be opened.

Any suggestions?

Edit: Restarting the Firefox reverted everything that changed with my delete tweak and problem yet persists and all of the configs I screwed are disappeared.

Edit2: Safe mode didn't make any difference. I've filled a bug report on chromium about it, yet didn't seemed to be popular yet. http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=255434

Comment: It only happens with Google?

Comment: Yes & I don't want to use duck or bing or yandex.

Comment: Does this only happen from certain locations?  Are you using wireless?

Comment: Sounds like someone is google scraping and getting throttled to me.

Comment: I tried with wired connection just now, same happened. Could it be something about country specific connection configurations? If so, I didn't made any work on this. Modem is fine with other OSs tho.

Comment: So what distro exactly are you using? Could you share its name and version?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu Raring (up-to-date) right now, I can confirm that it wasn't happening with arch but tell me, WHAT DIFFERENCE DOES IT MAKE?

Comment: Try starting Firefox in Safe Mode by closing all open instances and running the following command in a terminal window: `firefox -safe-mode`. [Source: MozillaZine KB](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Safe_Mode#Linux)

Answer (score -2):

I encountered the same kind of issue and I've fixed it by checking my /etc/hosts.

My computer was entered twice :

---

127.0.0.1   localhost

127.0.1.1   the_host_name <- I commented this line

---

Since I commented this line internet broswing is faster than ever.

Comment: There is a reason for the two entries: http://serverfault.com/questions/363095/what-does-127-0-1-1-represent-in-etc-hosts. Removing 127.0.1.1 is highly unlikely to have fixed the speed of connecting to the Internet, and may have the unintended side-effect of breaking other things.

Comment: I haven't tried the solution yet but I can say that it is highly possible that dudes in Debian might as well should have thought about that "unintended side-effects" before working around and hacking in an OS they build. However, for some unknown reason, the problem seems to be ceased by its own but I'm keeping in mind your answer and will try if encounter the same problem again. I'd really thank you for taking your time.